# How to separate alphanumeric characters from contiguous string in java?

Tags: java

"guid is: ": 956abcdefg25687qwe: true

I want to split 956abcdefg25687qwe and store it in a variable?

Comment: Please include the expected output along with the Java code you have already tried.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about what you want but you can use regular expressions with `replaceAll` method, like that:

```
String str = "956abcdefg25687qwe";
String str2 = str.replaceAll("[0-9]","");
String str3 = str.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]","");
System.out.println(str); // 956abcdefg25687qwe
System.out.println(str2); // abcdefgqwe
System.out.println(str3); // 95625687
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean, but I guess you want to use the *split* method from the **String** class: [Java 7 String.split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)).